# Checking Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have a data frame and want to know if a a certain string is present.
I want to know if any of the values in df[,1] contain anything from inscompany.

```
df = data.frame(company=c("KMart", "Shelter"), var2=c(5,7))
if( df[,1] == inscompany ) print("YES")
inscompany <- c("21st Century Auto Insurance", "AAA Auto Insurance", "AARP Auto Insurance",
        "Allstate Auto Insurance", "American Family Auto Insurance", "Eastwood Auto Insurance",
        "Erie Auto Insurance", "Farmers Auto Insurance", "GMAC Auto Insurance", "Hartford Auto Insurance",
        "Infinity Auto Insurance", "Mercury Auto Insurance", "Nationwide Auto Insurance", "Progressive Auto Insurance",
        "Shelter Insurance Company", "Titan Auto Insurance", "Travelers Auto Insurance", "USAA Auto Insurance")
```

I get an error message that it can only check the first value of inscompany to df[,1].

Help!

Comment: the inscompany assignement should also happen before the test. are you looking for exact matches or even partial? In your example you have "Shelter". Is that a match to Shelter Insurance Company?

Comment: I'm just looking for partial matches? So "Shelter" should be a match to "Shelter Insurance Company"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `%in%`. Here is an exampe:

```
R> chk <- c("A", "B", "Z")    # some text
R> chk %in% LETTERS[1:13]     # check for presence in first half of alphabet
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
R>
```

The `match()` function is related, see the help page for details.

Answer (score 1):

I think `match` and `%in%` won't work for partial matching.  `grepl` gives a logical (TRUE/FALSE) result depending on whether the target string is contained or not; I used `^` to enforce a match at the beginning of the string only (you may not need that).  `any` and `sapply` are needed to scale up to the many-to-many match.  If you just want to know whether *any* of the strings match, you need one more `any` around the whole thing.

```
 sapply(df$company,function(x) any(grepl(paste("^",x,sep=""),inscompany)))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```